# How can I get S rank?

Tags: resident-evil-3-2020

I have decided to go for the S rank now that I've finished the game on the different difficulty settings. I jumped on to the Standard and set out to do it. I decided to make things easier by using the infinite ammo handgun, which was unlocked in the shop.

I read that using infinite ammo guns wont void an S rank as there are guides saying the easiest way to do it on inferno is use infinite ammo rocket launcher.

I completed the game with all the requirements, finished in 2:11 (under 2:30) and saved less than 5 times (1). However, I didn't receive the S rank. Not even A. I got a B for some reason.

Does anyone know why this may have happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get S Rank in Standard mode, you need to beat the game in under **2 hours**, not 2:30. Beating the game in under two hours and thirty minutes is the time requirement for S Rank when playing Assisted mode - however, Standard's requirements are stricter. Each increased difficulty level through Hardcore cuts time from the maximum allowed to receive an S Rank.

For reference, the time requirements for every difficulty:

**Assisted**: 2:30

**Standard**: 2:00

**Hardcore**: 1:45

**Nightmare**: 2:00

**Inferno**: 2:00

([Source](https://gamewith.net/resident-evil-3/article/show/17382) and [Source](https://www.ign.com/wikis/re3-remake/How_to_Get_S-Rank_-_All_Requirements).)

Comment: Ahh. Didnt know it was stricter for that. The results screen only has it at 2:30. I only just missed out then. Spent too long getting all items as I thought I had time.... I assume A rank is same time requirements with no limit on saving then? In which case, I'll have to have another run without wasting time on items!